# Firebase RealtimeDB websocket connection times out on clients browsers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chromium

Overnight I've experienced websocket connection issues with Firebase RealtimeDB in browser environment.

As I'm building a ReactJS app using Vite, I initialize the database object like this:

```
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { Auth, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { Database, getDatabase } from 'firebase/database'

const FIREBASE_API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY

// all field are filled in with real data but I replaced them with placeholders here.
const firebaseApp: Readonly<FirebaseApp> = initializeApp({
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: '<auth_domain>',
  projectId: '<project_id>',
  databaseURL: '<my_database_url_id>',
  appId: '<my_app_id>',
  measurementId: '<my_measurementId>'
})

const firebaseAuth: Readonly<Auth> = getAuth(firebaseApp)

const db: Readonly<Database> = getDatabase(firebaseApp)

export { firebaseAuth, db }
```

Before, everying works, but now I'm getting those errors:
[image]
[image]

So anyone knows what's going on?

- The problem started to appear since the 10th of Nov 2023 (didn't change my code at all - it happened overnight).
- This happened with multiple users with different devices and different networks.
- Some users said that if they use Safari instead of Chrome the issue doesn't appear.
- I'm using Firebase JS SDK version 10.6.0.

**EDIT[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwwFO.jpg):
This is the code that causes the errors to appear:**

```
const aFunctionThatGetsCalledOnHomepageMounts = (...): Unsubscribe | null => {
  ...
  return onValue(
    ref(db, path, // db it the same db object mentioned in the code snippet above (imported).
    (snapshot) => {
     ...
    }
  )
}
```

**EDIT[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V6Pm.jpg):
More context:**

- The problem seems to be unrelated to Apple devices.
- Instead, the problem seems to be affecting Chromium-based browsers (Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge).

**EDIT[3]:
More error logs:**
[image]

[image]